# Чем можно проигрывать MP3 файлы в WIndows?

Tags: аудио, плеер, mp3

Подскажите библиотеку OpenSource для проигрывания файлов в Widnows? Хотел бы написать небольшой проигрыватель, но вот думаю под Windows или всетаки под Ubuntu делать!

Comment: гугл первая ссылка выдает нужные результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Есть такая библиотека BASS. Написана на C. Бесплатна для некоммерческих проектов. http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html

Answer (score 1):

JLayer под Java

Answer (score 1):

Если писать на Silverlight и WPF, то там MediaElement нативно понимает MP3 и еще кучу форматов.

Answer (score 0):

VLCPlayer http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html
И не только мр3, открывает все. Единственный плеер на свете!

Comment: Вы врете. Еще все открывает wmp classic в составе k-lite, gome player и еще туча плееров. Кстати VLC не проигрывает flv.

Автор - забудьте об этой идее. Это как минимум бессмысленно. Хотя например консольный плеер под win было бы интересно увидеть.

Comment: Консольный плеер под Windows есть (mpg123 портированный), но вы кстати увели в сторону. Я хотел API для проигрывания MP3.

Answer (score 0):

Да решений куча, тот же  bass, storm ... и иже с ними